# error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I plan to use C++ to make a random password generator (replacing python for speed), so I typed characters. When I input all characters, an error occurs:

```
warning: character constant too long for its type
 const unsigned char chars[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:'" + '",<.>/?'};
                                                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:3:123: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]
 const unsigned char chars[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:'" + '",<.>/?'};
```

```
#include <iostream>

const unsigned char chars[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:'" + '",<.>/?'};
//abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'",<.>/?
int main(){
    std::cout << chars;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `'",<.>/?'`? Another part of the string?

Comment: @DayDayNoBug You need to use escaped characters as for example \".

Comment: C++ doesn't use `'` string literals, it only uses them for single-character literals. Also, initializer list elements correspond 1:1 to the array elements, i.e. you're trying to init an unsigned char with a string literal. Please reduce your code (including the strings) to a minimum for a [mcve], that should make it much easier to read and see.

Answer (score 0):

You are using '",<.>/?' in the second part. You can normally use ' ' with chars. Use instead following with escape char \

```
#include <iostream>

const std::string chars= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:'\",<.>/?";

//abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'",<.>/?
int main(){
    std::cout << chars;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code (been fixed):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'",<.>/?
class generate{
    public:
        void generate_random_password(){
            const char* word = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:',<.>/?\"";
            cout << word;
        }
};
int main(){
    generate test;
    test.generate_random_password();
    int test2;
    std::cin >> test2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you added an answer by accident. There's a delete option - I see you already found the "edit question" option.